# CSS no sibling selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Consider the following html:

```
<div>
    <div class="iwant" />
    <div class="idontwant" />
</div>
 <div>
    <div class="iwant" />
</div>
```

I'm interested in a selector (for crawling content so I can't modify html) that would select all `iwant` that DO NOT have sibling with class `idontwant`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone still needs this, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74039701/6429674) . Based on it and on [:not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), the initial requirement can be accomplished using something like:

```
div:not(:has(+ .idontwant)) .iwant { 
  ... 
}
```

This approach has an advantage over the general sibling combinator: It also matches backwards, meaning something like:

```
<div>
    <div class="idontwant" />
    <div class="iwant" />
</div>
```

(so if you have the `.idontwant` element first -> case which would be ignored by the general sibling combinator)

---

Explanation:

1. `div:has(+ .idontwant)` would match any `div` that has a direct sibling with the class `idontwant`
2. `div:not(:has(+ .idontwant))` matches any `div` that doesn't have a direct sibling with class `idontwant`
3. All is left to do is search in the div that doesn't have a direct sibling with class `idontwant` for the class we want.

The selector is quite weird and big, but does the job, and I think there are (specific) cases where is quite needed.

Answer (score 76):

There is no sibling selector to match elements (or not) by class.

The closest selector I can think of is

```
.iwant:only-child
```

But this selector means that there cannot be any other elements besides that `div class="iwant"` as children of the parent `div`, regardless of type or class. This may fulfill your need depending on the structure of your HTML though, so it's worth a try. If class names are a problem for you, though, then there probably isn't much of a solution, because there isn't an `:only-of-class` pseudo-class in CSS which filters by class and ignores the rest.

Comment: It might be a solution but I prefer something more general because there might be extra `div`s. Good thinking though.

Answer (score 5):

There's no negative-sibling CSS selector. Use the sibling selector to set new styles, then reset the styles at the `.idontwant`:

```
div.iwant {
    /*Set CSS here*/
    display: inline;
}
div.iwant ~ div.idontwant {
    /*Reset CSS*/
    display: block /* Default of DIV is block*/
}
```

Comment: That's redundant since each class is mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BoltClock What do you mean by that? The `div.iwant ~ div.idontwant` selector is more specific than `div.iwant`.

Comment: I'm not setting styles, I want to get those element for crawler and I would prefer to do it in one query.

Answer (score 5):

There's no good way to target an item without a specific sibling item. But you can use `.iwant:last-child` to target items that doesn't have a subsequent sibling.

Example: http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/YyGgde

Answer (score 0):

This also might be helpful - if the element you want is always last-child:

```
div:last-child:not(.idontwant) {

}
```