# Not adding a css property to a last child inside a nested div- CSS

Tags: html, css, nested, css-selectors

I want to add certain property to a specific `<div>`, here's my structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  <div class="child2">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  <div class="child2">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to apply css border property on `class="child1"` except for the last `div` that has only class="child1". I tried:

```
.container {
   & > div.child1:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
   }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas around?

Comment: Your selector is wrong. You do not need the first > as the child divs are not DIRECT children of the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container .parent:not(:last-child) .child1{
  border-right: none;
}
```

You should select the last parent and in your case you're using ">" which selects a direct child of the container

Comment: @user1234 `Now I'm trying to apply css border property on class="child1" except for the last div THAT HAS ONLY class="child1"`, this answer will apply the CSS to child1 of all parents except the last parent, but **regardless of if that last parent has 1 child or multiple** it won't get the CSS

Comment: if he needs the parent that only has 1 child he could use :only-of-type. for example:  .container .parent .child1:only-of-type

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

You're trying to tell CSS to:

1. find **parent**s which have multiple children
2. then find specific child in each of these parent(s)

As of 2020, this is not supported by pure CSS, and the answer is ironically from 2009. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/134824), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45004/134824), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7866796/134824).

---

### Other Workarounds:

#### A) By jQuery (or similar solution by JS)

```
// Find all parents
$('.parent').each(function() {
    // Find all children of this parent
    var $children = $(this).find('div[class^="child"]');
    if($children.length > 1) {// if has 2 or more children
        $children.css('borderRight', 'none');
        // -- or --
        $children.addClass('my_child_no_border_class');
    } else {// Has 1 or 0 children
        $children.css('borderRight', '1px solid red');
        // -- or --
        $children.addClass('my_child_border_class');
    }
});
```

If you prefer adding classes, make sure to create CSS classes `.my_child_border_class` and `.my_child_no_border_class`

#### B) By HTML & CSS

Add special classes for children with border and no border:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1 noborder">
        <div class="child2">
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1 noborder">
        <div class="child2">
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1 withborder">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
.noborder {
    border-right: none;
}
.withborder {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

#### C) By CSS

```
/* All child1 get this css */
.parent > child1 {
    border-right: none;
}

/* then we override last parent's child1 with different css */
.parent:last-child > child1 {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

### Conclusion:

There might be other workarounds, but not pure CSS solution.

Comment: @user1234 added C

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. You do not need the first `>` as the child divs are not DIRECT children of the container

```css
 .container {
  width: 80%;
}

.container .child1:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}

.parent {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the last parent and child1 like this.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.child1 {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.parent:last-child > .child1 {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can **add a nother class** to the last **div** or an id so you can target it as follow:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="parent"> 
        <div class="child1"></div>
        <div class="child2"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="parent"> 
        <div class="child1"></div> 
        <div class="child2"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="parent"> 
        <div class="child1 last-child" id="child"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and css property as follow:

```
.last-child  {
 border-right: none;
 }
```