# If X is true then do this but if X is true & Y is false do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi what I'm trying to do is run a campaign where all products on the site will have a sale banner. Some products will already have a sale banner, but for the rest of the products that don't then i want to add a banner to these. I've been able to do this, but the issue i'm having is, if a product is Out of Stock then i don't want the sale banner to be added to these products.

I've created a snippet trying to show what i've got so far.

- Product 1 is a product that already has a sale banner.
- Product 2 is a product that doesn't have a sale banner
- Product 3 is a product that doesn't have a sale banner and is out of stock

Product 1 has a sale banner so nothing needs to be done to this. For Product 2 i want the sale banner to be added & for Product 3 i don't want a sale banner to be added as it is out of stock.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```js
$(".saleWrapper").each(function(index){
  if ($(this).children('.promoText').length === 0){
    $(this).append("<span class='promoText'>I'm ALSO on Sale</span>");
  }
})
```

```css
.product-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.promoText {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 1</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper">
      <span class="promoText">I'm on Sale</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 2</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper"></div>
</div>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 3</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper"></div>
  <div class="productOutOfStock">
    <p class="outOfStock">I'm Out Of Stock</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Go the other way:  `$(".product-slab__cta").closest(".product-slab__wrapper").find(".product-slab__markdown-promotion").append("<span class='product-slab__markdown-promotion-inner'><span class='promo-text'>ADD MESSAGE</span></span>");`

Comment: @freedomn-m I've completely reworded my question and updated my code as well, hope this makes more sense

Comment: There was nothing wrong with how the title/code was (the question text was a little confusing, but the comment clarified this - don't know why you got a downvote)

Comment: Here's a related question asking for "select X unless it has a sibling Y" (not sibling) - there's no selector for this, but there are work arounds.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866784/css-no-sibling-selector#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=There%20is%20no%20sibling%20selector,(or%20not)%20by%20class.&text=But%20this%20selector%20means%20that,regardless%20of%20type%20or%20class.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your help on this and for your explanations, works great thank you!

Comment: Sorry one last question @freedomn-m is there also a way to include another rule where if the href contains the string "bundle" in the url to exclude this product as well. So the code would look similar to this:
<div class="product-wrapper">
<a href="/product/bundle">Product 1</a>
  <div class="saleWrapper"></div>
</div>

Comment: You'll probably be better going to back to a `.each()` and applying multiple, *separate* `if` statements within that (or use `.filter()`).  Adding much more to the selector will make it unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated / reworded question is essentially the same and has the same problem.

Section 3's "out of stock" message is not a child of `.saleWrapper` - so you can't (easily) start at saleWrapper.

Instead, start at the `product-wrapper`, find the products that match, then locate the place to add the message.   See the original answer below for more details.

```js
$(".product-wrapper:not(:has(.promoText,.productOutOfStock))")
    .find(".saleWrapper")
    .append("<span class='promoText'>I'm ALSO on Sale</span>");
```

```css
.product-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.promoText {background: pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 1</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper">
      <span class="promoText">I'm on Sale</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 2</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper"></div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<p>Product 3</p>
  <div class="saleWrapper"></div>
  <div class="productOutOfStock">
    <p class="outOfStock">I'm Out Of Stock</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit: answer to original question**

> print the message on any products that don't have a sale banner i.e the second product only in this example

Within the `:has()` you can put any selector, in this case, you want the `,` selector (or).

```
:has(.product-slab__markdown-promotion-inner,.product-slab__cta)
```

However, your `__cta` is not inside the current `product-slab__markdown-promotion` so you have to start a level up at `product-slab__wrapper` - then once you have the correct `__wrapper`(s) you can then move back down into the location where you want to add the message, using `.find()`.

You can also remove the .each() as jquery already operates on collections

Giving:

```js
$(".product-slab__wrapper:not(:has(.product-slab__markdown-promotion-inner,.product-slab__cta))")
    .find(".product-slab__markdown-promotion")
    .append("<span class='product-slab__markdown-promotion-inner'><span class='promo-text'>ADD MESSAGE</span></span>");
```

```css
.product-slab__wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-slab__wrapper">
  <div class="product-slab__markdown-promotion">
    <div class="product-slab__markdown-promotion-inner">
      <span class="promo-text">20% discount</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-slab__stock"></div>
  <p>€0,00</p>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="product-slab__wrapper">
  <div class="product-slab__markdown-promotion">
  </div>
  <div class="product-slab__stock"></div>
  <p>€0,00</p>
</div>

<hr/>


<div class="product-slab__wrapper">
  <div class="product-slab__markdown-promotion"></div>
  <div class="product-slab__stock"><p class="btn btn__secondary btn__disabled product-slab__cta btn--full" disabled="">Out of stock</p></div>
  <p>€0,00</p>
</div>
```