# Select specific child TAG but only if parent has no other children or text

Tags: html, css

I would like to use a CSS selector to select a specific child TAG but only if parent has no other children or text.

In this specific case the `<a>` tag that needs to be selected is wrapped in a `<p>` tag.

I'm looking for a CSS-only solution (I'm curious to know if it's actually possible)

```
<p><a>This is selected</a></p> // selected
<p><a>This is NOT selected</a><span>other children</span></p> // NOT selected
<p><a>This is NOT selected</a>Other text</p> // NOT selected
```

Comment: @Austin - I got burnt by that yesterday as well.  Seems like maybe there's some new code that tries to collapse edits close in time and that it is a bit... overzealous.

Comment: Is it possible that your question is a duplicate of [CSS no sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866784/css-no-sibling-selector)?  If not, can you clarify how your question differs from the one at that link?

Comment: The missing part of [CSS no sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866784/css-no-sibling-selector) is that the Tag is Not selected also if it has other content that a sibling (for instance a simple text)

`<p><a>This is NOT selected</a>Other text</p> // NOT selected`

Comment: Thanks for explaining-- I have retracted my close vote.